# Where is my SQL Insert Error?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to modify records in my Microsoft Access database through c# in the .Net Framework.  This is my execution code, but I keep getting a Syntax Error from my INSERT statement and can't figure out why, can anyone help? I'm also experiencing some trouble where the SELECT statement, isn't returning any data which I KNOW exists in the database.  I've been at this for days and need a fresh pair of eyes, what could I be doing wrong?

This is the error:

> Error: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()   at ABM_Office_System.UpdateABMDatabaseWindow.b__0()...

```
for (int i = 0; i < hmuFinalList.Count; i++)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        stsW.StatusLbl.Content = "Updating " + hmuFinalList[i].MName + "'s records";
    });
    readcmd.Parameters.Clear();
    readcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [ABM] WHERE [M Name]=@";
    readcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", hmuFinalList[i].MName);
    Console.WriteLine("READCMD: " + readcmd.CommandText);
    Console.WriteLine("ReadcmdTRANSACTION: ");
    affected = readcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("affected: " + affected.ToString());
    if (affected > 0) //UPDATE TIME!
    {
        executecmd.Parameters.Clear();
        executecmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [ABM] SET "+
        "[M Type]=@," +
        "[M Component]=@," +
        "[M Birth Date]=@," +
        "[M Visa Expiration Date]=@," +
        "[M Residence Nation]=@," +
        "[M MTC]=@," +
        "[M MTC Date]=@," +
        "[M Arrival Date]=@," +
        "[M Release Date]=@, " +
        "[M Past Position]=@," +
        "[M Past Position Start Date]=@," +
        "[M Current Position Start Date]=@," +
        "[M Past Area]=@," +
        "[M Past Area Start Date],=@" +
        "[M Current Area Start Date]=@," +
        "[M Title - English]=@," +
        "[M Title - Non-English]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Type]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Last Name]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Given Name]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Language]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Comment]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Title]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Relationship]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun - Subject]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun - Object]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun - Possessive]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun - Other]=@," +
        "[M Previous Address Line 1]=@," +
        "[M Previous Address City]=@," +
        "[M Previous Address State/Province]=@,"
        + "[M Previous Address Postal Code]=@," +
        "[M Previous Address Country]=@," +
        "[M Type Plural]=@," +
        "[M Transfer Effective Date]=@," +
        "[M Position is a Promotion]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun Cap - Subject]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun Cap - Object]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun Cap - Possessive]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun Cap - Other]=@," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Title - Envelope]=@," +
        "[M Where Born]=@" +
        "WHERE [M Name]=@";

        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MType) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MType);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MComponent) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MComponent);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MBirthDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MBirthDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MVisaExpirationDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MVisaExpirationDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MResidenceNation) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MResidenceNation);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MMTC) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MMTC);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MMTCDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MMTCDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MArrivalDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MArrivalDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MReleaseDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MReleaseDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPastPosition) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPastPosition);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPastPositionStartDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPastPositionStartDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MCurrentPositionStartDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MCurrentPositionStartDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPastArea) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPastArea);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPastAreaStartDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPastAreaStartDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MCurrentAreaStartDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MCurrentAreaStartDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MTitleEnglish) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MTitleEnglish);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MTitleNonEnglish) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MTitleNonEnglish);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentType) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentType);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentLastName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentLastName);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentGivenName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentGivenName);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentLanguage) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentLanguage);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentComment) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentComment);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentTitle) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentTitle);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentRelationship) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentRelationship);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounSubject) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounSubject);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounObject) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounObject);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounPossessive) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounPossessive);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounOther) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounOther);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressLine1) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressLine1);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressCity) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressCity);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressStateProvince) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressStateProvince);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressPostalCode) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressPostalCode);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressCountry) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressCountry);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MTypePlural) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MTypePlural);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MTransferEffectiveDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MTransferEffectiveDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPositionisaPromotion) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPositionisaPromotion);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapSubject) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapSubject);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapObject) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapObject);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapPossessive) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapPossessive);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapOther) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapOther);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentTitleEnvelope) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentTitleEnvelope);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MWhereBorn) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MWhereBorn);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@", hmuFinalList[i].MName);
        Console.WriteLine("HMU UPDATE EXECUTION: " + executecmd.CommandText);
        executecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else //INSERT TIME!
    {
        executecmd.Parameters.Clear();
        executecmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [ABM] ([M Name],[M Type],[M Component],[M Birth Date],[M Visa Expiration Date],[M Residence Nation],"+
        "[M MTC]," +
        "[M MTC Date],"+
        "[M Arrival Date],"+
        "[M Release Date], "+
        "[M Past Position],"+
        "[M Past Position Start Date]," +
        "[M Current Position Start Date]," +
        "[M Past Area],"+
        "[M Past Area Start Date],"+
        "[M Current Area Start Date],"+
        "[M Title - English],"+
        "[M Title - Non-English],"+
        "[M HMU Correspondent Type],"+
        "[M HMU Correspondent Last Name]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Given Name]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Language]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Comment]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Title]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Address Line 1]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Relationship]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun - Subject]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun - Object]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun - Possessive]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun - Other]," +
        "[M Previous Address Line 1],"+
        "[M Previous Address City]," +
        "[M Previous Address State/Province],"+
        "[M Previous Address Postal Code]," +
        "[M Previous Address Country],"+
        "[M Type Plural]," +
        "[M Transfer Effective Date],"+
        "[M Position is a Promotion]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun Cap - Subject]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun Cap - Object]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun Cap - Possessive]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Pronoun Cap - Other]," +
        "[M HMU Correspondent Title - Envelope]," +
        "[M Where Born],)"+
        "VALUES(@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@,@)";
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MName);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MType) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MType);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MComponent) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MComponent);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MBirthDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MBirthDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MVisaExpirationDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MVisaExpirationDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MResidenceNation) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MResidenceNation);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MMTC) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MMTC);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MMTCDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MMTCDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MArrivalDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MArrivalDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MReleaseDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MReleaseDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPastPosition) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPastPosition);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPastPositionStartDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPastPositionStartDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MCurrentPositionStartDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MCurrentPositionStartDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPastArea) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPastArea);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPastAreaStartDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPastAreaStartDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MCurrentAreaStartDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MCurrentAreaStartDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MTitleEnglish) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MTitleEnglish);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MTitleNonEnglish) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MTitleNonEnglish);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentType) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentType);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentLastName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentLastName);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentGivenName) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentGivenName);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentLanguage) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentLanguage);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentComment) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentComment);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentTitle) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentTitle);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentAddressLine1) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentAddressLine1);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentRelationship) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentRelationship);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounSubject) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounSubject);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounObject) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounObject);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounPossessive) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounPossessive);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounOther) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounOther);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressLine1) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressLine1);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressCity) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressCity);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressStateProvince) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressStateProvince);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressPostalCode) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressPostalCode);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressCountry) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPreviousAddressCountry);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MTypePlural) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MTypePlural);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MTransferEffectiveDate) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MTransferEffectiveDate);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MPositionisaPromotion) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MPositionisaPromotion);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapSubject) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapSubject);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapObject) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapObject);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapPossessive) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapPossessive);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapOther) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentPronounCapOther);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentTitleEnvelope) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].CorrespondentTitleEnvelope);
        executecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@",string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmuFinalList[i].MWhereBorn) ? (object)DBNull.Value : hmuFinalList[i].MWhereBorn);
        Console.WriteLine("HMU INSERT EXECUTION: " + executecmd.CommandText);
        executecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

}
```

This is driving me crazy!

Comment: There's an extra comma on the last line: `[M Where Born],)`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: When I'm having trouble with a complicated SQL statement, I will usually collect the final sql string created just before the program executes it, and try to run it directly in the database.  Sometimes it makes errors more clear that way.

Comment: This code would be a good candidate for using an ORM

Comment: @CindyH I did think about that, how can I look at the final string AFTER the parameter values have been inserted into the command?

Comment: I don't exactly remember.  Put a breakpoint on the line that says executecmd.ExecuteNonQuery.  When you get there, hover over executecmd, and explore its properties until you find the sql value.  (or look in the immediate window or the watch window if you prefer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert column list ends with a comma when it shouldn't.

Replace

```
        "[M Where Born],)"+
```

With

```
        "[M Where Born])"+
```